# format date according to the my sql date format

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, date, datepicker

I am using Pikaday JavaScript Datepicker and it give me a date like( Wed May 14 2014). I want to change it to the MySQL data format YYYY-MM-DD. but I am unable to identify what should I change to get that format. some one can please help me.

[Pikaday JavaScript Datepicker- github](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday)

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL you can get the date with the function [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and the appropriate format:

```
STR_TO_DATE(yourvalue, '%a %b %d %Y')
```

You find the formats by the [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function. I'm sure there's a javascript solution too.